# I want to parse this website url "https://www.171chryslerdodgejeepram.com/" to get value of DealerId but I have no idea how to do it

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script").Where(x => x.InnerHtml.Contains("DealerId:")))
{


}
```

I am trying to get value of dealer id with the help of above code but it is not returning anything, but if you trying to find DealerId from page source of above website then it is there. please help me to achieve this or if anything wrong with above code then please correct me.

Comment: try `Contains("dealerId:")`

Comment: Thanks @cerberus that was a silly mistake from my side.Now will you please tell me how can I get the value corresponding to dealerId

Answer (score 0):

1. you can parse JS code with something like (https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) and extract the field you need from JS object
2. you can simple find this text (not elegant, but works):

**UPD1: regex version**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var url = "https://www.171chryslerdodgejeepram.com/";
        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = web.Load(url);

        foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script").Where(x => x.InnerHtml.Contains("dealerId:")))
        {
            var s = node.InnerText;
            Regex r = new Regex(@"dealerId:\s+'(\d+)'");
            Match m = r.Match(s);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Tried above but it is giving me empty string. @cerberus

Comment: @cereberus still its giving empty value

Comment: @jiga show me your code, i executed my example many times and it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

```
 var url = "https://www.171chryslerdodgejeepram.com/";
        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = web.Load(url);
 foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script").Where(x => x.InnerHtml.ToLower().Contains("dealerid")))
                {
                    AdwordsAccount info = new AdwordsAccount();
                    var s = node.InnerText;
                    //Regex r = new Regex("dealerid(.*?)\",");
                    Regex r = new Regex(@"dealerId:\s+'(\d+)'");
                    Match m = r.Match(s.ToLower());
                    info.account = m.Groups[1].Value;
                    urlinfo.adwordsaccount.Add(info);
                }
```

@cereberus this is my code

Comment: `Match m = r.Match(s.ToLower());` modify to `Match m = r.Match(s);`